# PMF for sum of uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent integer valued random variables that both are
uniformly distributed on {1, 2, . . . n}. What is the PMF for S := $X_1$ + $X_2$?

What I have so far: P(S=$X_1$+$X_2$) = $\sum_{i=1}^{S-1} P($$X_1$$=i, $$X_2$$=S-i)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{S-1} (\frac1n*\frac1n)$ = $\frac{S-1}{n^2}$

But I don't think this is the answer because there is no way the probability keeps going higher as S goes higher.
Can someone help me out please.

Comment: Laziness might be the cause of your sorrow... Following the path you explain, but much more carefully, one gets for every nonnegative integer $s$, $$P(S=s)=\sum_{i=1}^n P(X_1=i)P(X_2=s-i)=\sum_i\frac1n\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\frac1n\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant s-i\leqslant n}=\sum_{i=\max(1,s-n)}^{\min(s-1,n)}\frac1{n^2}=\ldots$$ from which the real formula for $P(S=s)$ arises directly, for example considering separately the cases $2\leqslant s\leqslant n$ and $n+1\leqslant s\leqslant2n$.

Comment: @Did Excuse me but I don't really quite understand why you denoted the sum as i=max(1, s-n) to min(s-1, n). By observing the pattern I obtained the result (n-|s-(n+1)|)/n^2, but I haven't figured out how to obtain the result through general calculation.

Comment: $1\leq i\leq n\wedge1\leq s-i\leq n\iff\max(1,s-n)\leq i\leq\min(s-1,n)$

Comment: What @drhab explained.